# Spring: How to export objects methods via non-HTTP protocol

Tags: java, spring, scala, rpc

I have a collection of stateless scala/Java APIs, which might look like:

```
class UserService {
  def get(id: UserIDType): User { ... }
  def update( user:User): User { ... }
  ...
}
```

where User has a set of inspectable bean properties. I'd like to make these *same* APIs not only available over HTTP (which I know how to do), but also other, more performant non-HTTP protocols (ideally also running in the same process as the HTTP server). And more importantly, automate as much as possible including generation of client APIs that match the original Java API, and the dispatching of method calls following network requests.

I've found  [Spring's guide on remoting](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/remoting.html) 
However, this looks limited to HTTP (text not binary). What I'd really love is a library/other method that:

- lets me scan for registered/annotated services and describes methods and parameters as data
- lets me easily dispatch method calls (so that I'm in control of the sockets, communication protocols and whatnot and can chose a more performant one than HTTP).

i.e. the kinds of things that Spring's DispatcherServlet does internally, but without the HTTP limitations.

Ideas?

**Background**

I'd like to make a set of stateless service API calls available as network services with the following goals:

1. Some of the APIs should be available as REST calls from web pages/mobile clients
2. A *superset* of these APIs should be available internally within our company (e.g. from C++ libraries, python libraries) in a way that is **as high-performance** (read low-latency) **as possible**, particularly when the service and client are:

   - co-located in the same process, or
   - co-located on the same machine.
3. automate wrapper code for the client and server. If I add a method a service API, or and an attribute to a class, no-one should have to *write* additional code in client or server. (e.g. I hit a button and a new client API that matches the original Java/scala service is auto-generated).

(1) is easily achievable with Spring MVC. Without duplication of classes I can simply markup the service: (i.e. service is also a controller)

```
@Controller
@Service
@RequestMapping(...)
class UserService {
  @RequestMapping(...)
  def get(@PathVariable("id") id: UserIDType): User { ... }

  @RequestMapping(...)
  def update( @RequestBody user:User): User { ... }
  ...
}
```

With tools like Swagger (3) is easily achievable (I can trivially read the Swagger-generated JSON spec and can auto-generate C++ or Python code that mimics the original service class, it's methods, parameter names and the POJO parameter types).

However, HTTP is not particularly performant, so I'd like to use a different (binary) protocol here. Trivially, I can use the this same spec to generate a thrift .idl or even directly generate client code to talk Thrift/ProtocolBuffers (or any other binary protocol) while also providing to the client an API that looks just like the original Java/scala one.

Really -- the only tricky part is getting a description of the service method and then actually dispatching a method calls. So -- are there libraries to help me do that?

---

Notes:
I'm aware that mixing service and controller annotations disgusts some Spring MVC purists. However, my goal really is to have a logical API, and automate all of the service embodiments of it (i.e. the controller part is redundant boilerplate that should be auto-generated). I'd *REALLY* rather not spend my life writing boilerplate code.

Comment: I think you're underestimating the performance of HTTP.  Only the headers are text, the rest can be binary.  If you convert things to text before transmitting them, then yes, performance will not be good.